# How do I make a mega menu start on the left instead of right under the link

Tags: html, css

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rmle.png)

I want my dropdown menu to start all the way on the left instead of the right side of the menu. I have tried using properties such as left:0; on .dropdown to no avail. How can it get it to start from the left instead of starting right under the button?

Relevant Code

```
.dropdown{
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
left:0;
width: 100vw;
transform: translateY(10px);
opacity: 0;
pointer-events: none;
transition: .5s;
}

.dropdown ul{
position: absolute;

}
```

Comment: edit your post and include your code so we can help.. and read [mre] to get fast answer for your questions

Comment: Sorry I posted the wrong link!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i'm reading it correctly you'll need to add this line

left:-150px; This will move the menu to the left of its current position just amend the pixels as you wish.

```
.dropdown{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left:-150px;
    width: 100vw;
    transform: translateY(10px);
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: .5s;
}
```